# main.jsbundle is an empty file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-code-push

Greeting!

I'm on a task to upgrade RN from 0.41 to 0.50.4 and I'm running into a weird problem.
My App runs fine when XCode Build Configuration is DEBUG on simulator. However, when I change Build Configuration to RELEASE. App crashes immediately on launch.

```
Failed to load bundle(file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../main.jsbundle) with error:(Error reading bundle /var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../main.jsbundle (null))
```

I have code push integrated into my app, thus I am using `jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];`

Since running RELEASE mode on iOS device doesn't work. I also tried to run on iOS Simulator with RELEASE Build Config, and the error shows to be

```
Failed to load bundle(file:///Users/<NAME>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EF0AE02-83AF-48DF-9E61-97ADB610D8DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/78801DB5-7D2D-4108-9D90-70B457AB6915/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle) with error:(Error reading bundle /Users/Tsunghan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EF0AE02-83AF-48DF-9E61-97ADB610D8DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/78801DB5-7D2D-4108-9D90-70B457AB6915/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle (null))
```

When I actually going into find that `main.jsbundle`. It appears to be an **empty file.**

I've created an offline `main.jsbundle` and linked with XCode project, it doesn't fix the issue.

I've also tried these solutions:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1066
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15432

But didn't fix the issue either.

**It seems like on building through `react-native-xcode.sh`, somehow it generates empty `main.jsbundle` file**
Has anyone solve this issue? Any help is appreciated!

RN version: v0.50.4
RN-code-push version: v5.2.1
node v8.1.0
npm v5.0.3

***UPDATE:***
I solved it by setting nvm 8.1.0 as default